# Trying to add vlookup to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to create a formula that will check if a cell has a value in Column B and then input a vlookup in column A.  As a standard formula it would look like

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'Date Shown'!A:E,7,FALSE)
```

I would want the lookup value to change based on the cell thats originally being check.  I have the below formula that can check and add a value to the adjacent cell, which i tried to modify for a vlookup, but don't have the knowledge to create a vlookup properly.  I appreciate any help, thanks!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim r As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

With Sheets("Date Hidden")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each r In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            r.Offset(0, -1).result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Date Hidden").Range("A2"), Sheets("Date Shown")A:G, 7, False)
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Subs
```

Date Shown sheet:

Column A   // Column G

Jane     /   /      10/1/17

Date Hidden Sheet

Column A    //Column B
(empty)  //  Jane

Comment: `Sheets("Date Shown")A:G` should be `Sheets("Date Shown").Range("A:G")`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I'm getting the following error "Unable to get vlookup value of the worksheet function class"  Any ideas?

Comment: @EricL Do you know if that value exists in the array? It seems like it can't find it.

Comment: On sheet "date Hidden" Column B has data i'm trying to vlookup, On sheet "Date Shown" Columns A:G have data, with Column A having the same identifier as the "date Hidden"s column B.  So column B in the first sheet has a cells with values "3", "4", and "5" and those same values are also in some cells in the second sheets column A.

Comment: What happens when you change `r.Offset(0, -1).result =` to `r.Offset(0, -1).Value =`? I don't believe `result` is a valid property.

Comment: That gets a value! but it seems to only be pulling cell b2 to run,  how would i have it check b3, b4 and so on as it goes down the line?

Comment: When you step through your code (using F8), and then float over `LastRow`, what value are you getting?

Comment: I get LastRow=0

Comment: So is there no data in Column B of `Date Hidden`? What about in `B2` on `Date Hidden`? Because if not, then it can't loop with an invalid range of `B2:B0`.

Comment: Theres data in all these cells.  I think i need to change VLookup(Sheets("Date Hidden").Range("A2".  First it should be column B (changed it right after posting) and then it should be If the vlookup is running on line 5 it should pulling b5, line 6 should be pulling b6 as the lookup value.

Answer (score 0):

Changed a little your code:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim date_hidden_range As Range
    Dim last_row As Long

    With Sheets("Date Hidden")
        last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Set date_hidden_range = .Range("B2:B" & last_row)

        For i = 1 To date_hidden_range.Cells.Count
            If date_hidden_range(i).Value <> "" Then
                MsgBox date_hidden_range(i).Value
                date_hidden_range(i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Date Hidden").Range("A" & i), Sheets("Date Shown").Range("A:G"), 7, False)
            End If
        Next i

    End With

    End Sub
```

**Option 2**

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell_range As Range
    Dim date_hidden_range As Range
    Dim last_row As Long

    With Sheets("Date Hidden")
        last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        Set date_hidden_range = .Range("B2:B" & last_row)

        For Each cell_range In date_hidden_range
        i = 2
            If cell_range(i).Value <> "" Then
                MsgBox cell_range(i).Value
                cell_range(i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Date Hidden").Range("A" & i), Sheets("Date Shown").Range("A:G"), 7, False)
            End If
        i = i + 1
        Next cell_range

    End With

    End Sub
```

Check how this work's, hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi R_Student, Not sure what the msg box is for. I've tried my best to enter an example on my first post. I need whatever vlookup runs to enter that data into Column A of "Date Hidden" Sheet.  There are maybe 200 lines of unique identifiers for this to run on.  It seems like your macro is just using line 2's unique ID to add the date for everybody.